# (Python Crash Course) Alien Invasion Project

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I would very appreciate if someone could tell me how to fix this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Ship' object has no attribute 'bullet_width'
```

I am starting to learn Python, and I'm not sure what the solution to this would be. This always happens when I press the space bar.
Below are the modules in this project:

alien_invasion.py:

```
    import sys
    import pygame
    from settings import Settings
    from ship import Ship
    import game_functions as gf
    from pygame.sprite import Group

    def run_game():
        pygame.init()
        ai_settings = Settings()
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
            (ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1100, 600))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")
        bg_color = (230, 230, 230)
        ship = Ship(screen, ai_settings)
        bullets = Group()
        while True:
            gf.check_events(ship, screen, ai_settings, bullets)
            ship.update()
            bullets.update()
            gf.update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                     sys.exit()
            screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
            ship.blitme()
            screen.fill(bg_color)

    run_game()
```

ship.py:

```
    import pygame
    class Ship():
        def __init__(self, screen, ai_settings):
            self.screen = screen
            self.ai_settings = ai_settings
            self.image = pygame.image.load('images/spaceship.png')
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
            self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
            self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom
            self.center = float(self.rect.centerx)
            self.moving_right = False
            self.moving_left = False
        def update(self):
            if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
                self.center += self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
            if self.moving_left and self.rect.left > 0:
                self.center -= self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
            self.rect.centerx = self.center

        def blitme(self):
            self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

bullet.py:

```
    import pygame
    from pygame.sprite import Sprite

    class Bullet(Sprite):
        def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen, ship):
            super(Bullet, self).__init__()
            self.screen = screen

            self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, ai_settings.bullet_width,
                            ai_settings.bullet_height)
            self.rect.centerx = ship.rect.top

            self.y = float(self.rect.y)
            self.color = ai_settings.bullet_color
            self.speed_factor = ai_settings.bullet_speed_factor

    def update(self):
            self.y -= self.speed_factor
            self.rect.y = self.y

    def draw_bullet(self):
            pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.color, self.rect)
```

game_functions.py

```
    import sys
    import pygame
    from bullet import Bullet

    def check_keydown_events(event, ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            ship.moving_right = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            ship.moving_left = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            new_bullet = Bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship)
            bullets.add(new_bullet)
    def check_keyup_events(event, ship):
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            ship.moving_right = False
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            ship.moving_left = False
    def check_events(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                check_keydown_events(event, ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                check_keyup_events(event, ship)


    def update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
        screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
        for bullet in bullets.sprites():
            bullet.draw_bullet()
        ship.blitme()
        pygame.display.flip()
```

settings.py:

```
    class Settings():
        def __init__(self):
            self.screen_width = 1200
            self.screen_height = 800
            self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)
            self.ship_speed_factor = 1.5

            self.bullet_speed_factor = 1
            self.bullet_width = 3
            self.bullet_height = 15
            self.bullet_color = 60, 60, 60
```

Comment: Looks like that for some reason `ai_settings` becomes `ship` (maybe the Super call) but this is not really solvable from here. You'll need to start a debugger and go step by step until you find the moment when the error happens.

Comment: `check_events(ship, screen, ai_settings, bullets)` -> `check_events(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)`

Comment: I just changed it, and I'm glad to say that it works! But why does the order of that matter?

Comment: @JackBrown Please learn the basics. The order of the arguments matters, except of [Keyword Arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#positional-or-keyword-arguments).

Comment: order of the arguments matters in all languages (except keyword arguments). Languages don't care how you name variables - you may have different names outside function and inside function - they care for position of arguments

Comment: @JackBrown Those are positional arguments. You could change the function calls to make them keyword arguments, and then the order wouldn't matter. This project got restructured in the second edition of the book, so that the [overall game is a class](https://github.com/ehmatthes/pcc_2e/blob/master/chapter_12/piloting_the_ship/alien_invasion.py). The functions became methods, and there are way fewer arguments to keep track of. (I'm the author of PCC.)

Answer (score 0):

The order of the arguments is wrong when you call `check_events`:

<s>`check_events(ship, screen, ai_settings, bullets)`</s>

```py
check_events(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
```

The order of the arguments matters, except of [Keyword Arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#positional-or-keyword-arguments).